# Sum custom time durations

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have several time fields in the format dd:hh:mm:ss

| Sample Data |
| --- |
| 00:00:00:00 |
| 12:09:54:47 |
| 00:01:14:23 |
| 00:00:00:00 |

I would like to add all the values to calculate the total.

I've done some reading and I know you can't simply sum them together as it "resets" each time you reach 24.

I found you can use the following formula but it doesn't seem to take into account days.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(C2:C8))), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Are these text strings or numbers?  If you add `1` to the cell containing `12:09:54:47` what is the result?  For example if that duration is in cell `A2` then what does the formula `=A2+1` in a separate cell return?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, "dd:hh:mm:ss" is not a valid duration format. You can do this with some manipulation, considering the first two digits as the days for one step, and the rest for the time:

```
=LET(total,SUM(MAP(C:C,LAMBDA(each,
IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(each,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(each,8)))))),
INT(total)&":"&TEXT(total,"HH:mm:ss"))
```

[image]